# D8: Program type already present: com.MyCompany.Game.BuildConfig

Tags: c#

I get this error after i add GoogleMobileAds plugin into my project. I have shared codes of AndroidManifest.xml of GoogleMobileAds plugin. Can anyone please help ?

(UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179))

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.MyCompany.Game" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <application>
    <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" />
    <activity
      android:isGame="true"
      android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
      android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-1010101010101010~1010101010" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Is your company really named "DefaultCompany"?

Comment: I have changed it and there are same errors...I think name is not the thing which causes this problem.

Comment: I do what's told at (https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start) but get errors...I can't understand :/